# How to elegantly check for existence of a record in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a better way to check for the existence of a record in RSpec?

```
Foo.where(bar: 1, baz:2).count.should == 1
```

Comment: Could you try `Foo.where(bar: 1, baz:2).should_not be_empty`?

Answer (score 50):

With [Rspec 2.13.0](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers%3aexist), I was able to do

```
Foo.where(bar: 1, baz: 2).should exist
```

---

**Edit:**

Rspec now has [an expect syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax):

```
expect(Foo.where(bar: 1, bax: 2)).to exist
```

Comment: `expect(Foo.find_by_bar(1)).to be_present` when you're using finders

Comment: `present?` is 68 times slower than `exists?` according to this behchmark: https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/benchmark/performance/rails/present-vs-any-vs-exists.html

Answer (score 21):

For rspec-rails > 3.0

Having a Blog model,

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  it 'creates a post' do
    post :create, blog: { title: 'blog title' }

    # Returns true if the post was successfully added
    expect(Blog.where(title: 'blog title')).to be_present
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the expect syntax:

```
expect(Foo.where(bar: 1, baz: 2)).not_to be_empty
expect(Foo.where(bar: 1, baz: 2)).to exist
```

Answer (score 7):

use `Foo.exists?(bar: 1, baz: 2).should be_true`

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo.where(bar: 1, baz: 2).exists?.should be_true
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
expect(Foo.where(bar: 1, baz:2)).not_to be nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
RSpec.describe Foo do
  let(:foo_attributes) { { bar: 1, baz: 2 } }
  before { FactoryBot.create(:foo, **foo_attributes) }
  subject { Foo.where foo_attributes }

  it { is_expected.to exist }
end
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.